# Loop through XML & Read value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL query which can return n  number of the row. Each row has below-mentioned sample XML. I want to read Sample Plan ID & insert into a temp table.
Please help me.

Please see below sample XML:

```
<AvailSampleUpdateRS xmlns="http://www.abcconnect.com/EQC/AR/2007/02">
    <Success>
        <Warning code="1011">Sample date 2016-12-30; Room Type ID 20583; Sample Plan ID 207782211; Inactive Sample Plan Updated Ref=[b44d7e4e-cf66-11e6-950b-e19b2852ebb6] </Warning>
        <Warning code="1022">Sample date 2016-12-31; Room Type ID 20583; Sample Plan ID 207782211; Inactive Sample Plan Updated Ref=[b44d7e4e-cf66-11e6-950b-e19b2852ebb6] </Warning>
        <Warning code="7023">Sample date 2017-01-02; Room Type ID 20583; Sample Plan ID 203619420; Inactive Sample Plan Updated Ref=[b44d7e4e-cf66-11e6-950b-e19b2852ebb6] </Warning>
        <Warning code="1011">Sample date 2017-01-03; Room Type ID 20583; Sample Plan ID 203619420; Inactive Sample Plan Updated Ref=[b44d7e4e-cf66-11e6-950b-e19b2852ebb6] </Warning>
        <Warning code="7025">Sample date 2017-01-04; Room Type ID 20583; Sample Plan ID 203619420; Inactive Sample Plan Updated Ref=[b44d7e4e-cf66-11e6-950b-e19b2852ebb6] </Warning>
    </Success>
</AvailSampleUpdateRS>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try [XMl query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type)

Answer (score 0):

Try below SQL code.
Hope this will help you to START.

```
Declare @xml XML

Set @XML = '<AvailSampleUpdateRS xmlns="http://www.abcconnect.com/EQC/AR/2007/02">
  <Success>
    <Warning code="1011">Sample date 2016-12-30; Room Type ID 20583; Sample Plan ID 207782211; Inactive Sample Plan Updated Ref=[b44d7e4e-cf66-11e6-950b-e19b2852ebb6] </Warning>
    <Warning code="1022">Sample date 2016-12-31; Room Type ID 20583; Sample Plan ID 207782211; Inactive Sample Plan Updated Ref=[b44d7e4e-cf66-11e6-950b-e19b2852ebb6] </Warning>
    <Warning code="7023">Sample date 2017-01-02; Room Type ID 20583; Sample Plan ID 203619420; Inactive Sample Plan Updated Ref=[b44d7e4e-cf66-11e6-950b-e19b2852ebb6] </Warning>
    <Warning code="1011">Sample date 2017-01-03; Room Type ID 20583; Sample Plan ID 203619420; Inactive Sample Plan Updated Ref=[b44d7e4e-cf66-11e6-950b-e19b2852ebb6] </Warning>
    <Warning code="7025">Sample date 2017-01-04; Room Type ID 20583; Sample Plan ID 203619420; Inactive Sample Plan Updated Ref=[b44d7e4e-cf66-11e6-950b-e19b2852ebb6] </Warning>
  </Success>
</AvailSampleUpdateRS>'


SELECT 
    x.y.value('local-name(..)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') parentElementName,
    x.y.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') elementName,
    x.y.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') elementValue
    Into #Temp
FROM @xml.nodes('//*[not(*)]') AS x(y)


select SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(elementValue, CHARINDEX('Sample Plan ID', elementValue), 
CHARINDEX(';', elementValue)+1), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
SUBSTRING(elementValue, CHARINDEX('Sample Plan ID', elementValue), CHARINDEX(';', elementValue)+1)), 
LEN(SUBSTRING(elementValue, CHARINDEX('Sample Plan ID', elementValue), CHARINDEX(';', elementValue)+1))) as SampleDataID
From #Temp
```